# Connecting Redis localhost from Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I have a Node.js application where I use Redis, I am trying to connect the Docker container and the locally running Redis.

Tried solutions:

1. vim /usr/local/etc/redis.conf

   Updated

   ```
   bind 127.0.0.1
   ```

   To

   ```
   bind 0.0.0.0
   ```

   Stopped the redis and start it again and tried running the docker
2. With the above thing tried running `docker run -p 4000:8080 -p 6379:6379 -t node-app`

Both above didn't worked getting the below error

```
Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Update: I am checking it on Mac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: docker run -p 8080:8080  -p 6379:6379 --network="bridge"  -t node-app getting this error Error starting listen tcp 0.0.0.0:6379: bind: address already in use.

Comment: docker run -p 8080:8080  -p 6379:6379 --network="host"  -t capacity-node  this gives the same error Error: Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: Bind `redis` instance to localhost instead of `0.0.0.0`. Verify you can connect from docker host to redis before starting working with docker. Then stop and rm all running containers of `node-app`. Finally start docker container  `docker run  --network="host" -t node-app`. It should work. Note it is not required to specify exposed ports as with network mode host all container's exposed ports are automatically exposed to docker's host.

Comment: "docker.for.mac.localhost" instead of localhost or '127.0.0.1' will work :), it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

`"docker.for.mac.localhost"` instead of `localhost or '127.0.0.1'` will work :), it worked for me on mac machine.

Comment: Mac is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: i didn't tagged platform as mac on it, sorry on that. added the info of the platform on the question. Thank you @mfnx

Comment: Why not simply access your localhost via de Docker0 network interface? From within the container, the ip 172.17.0.1 should point to your machine localhost.

Comment: should but it didn't

redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 113 connecting to 172.26.0.1:6379. No route to host.

Answer (score 4):

In Dockerfile add this
Docker v19.03

```
ENV REDIS_HOST "redis://host.docker.internal"
```

when i using it on node.js

```
const REDIS_HOST = process.env.REDIS_HOST ? process.env.REDIS_HOST : ""
const client = redis.createClient(REDIS_HOST)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need the port also?

Answer (score 2):

If you use default networking (`--network="bridge"`), you could simply use the IP address of the gateway between the Docker host and the bridge network, i.e. `172.17.0.1`. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) is the documentation. This would work on all platforms, not only on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the docker internal host in your node app's config.json file:

```
"redisHost": "host.docker.internal"
```

You don't need to change any Redis configuration on your local.